# Spring Boot Validation Set Parameter Name Provider

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I had a Validator bean that used the `ReflectionParameterNameProvider` to return correct reflected variables names e.g. `methodName.myVarName` as oppose to `methodName.arg0`

```
@Bean
public Validator validator() {
    final ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byDefaultProvider()
            .configure()
            .parameterNameProvider(new ReflectionParameterNameProvider())
            .buildValidatorFactory();
    return validatorFactory.getValidator();
```

This worked correctly but does not `Autowire` beans in my custom validator.
To enable beans to autowire in my `ConstraintValidator` I must use.

```
@Bean
public Validator validator() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}
```

However I cannot then use the `ReflectionParameterNameProvider`.

**Question**

How do I use the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` with `ReflectionParameterNameProvider`?

Answer (score 0):

Spring's `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` should include a [`DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer.html) which in turn should rely on [`StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer.java). Is it not working for you? Are you on Java 8? The `StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer` should be pretty similar to `ReflectionParameterNameProvider`